# C Table implemented by an array

Tags: c, arrays

Basically I'm trying to implement a table with help of an array. The array functionality is already given and should not be altered. What I'm having trouble configuring is my table_remove function. Keep in mind that I'm not striving for the most effective way to do this.

What I tried to do is loop through the entire table to find if there is a key that matches.

If the key is found, save the position.
If not exit.

So after the position is found I set it to free the key & value on that position in hope that it will 'remove' the key & value pair from that position. However, my given test program returns "Removing the last element from a table does not result in an empty table.". If I add in the end "array_setVal(array, NULL, index) then the entire program crashes (Probably because it tries to write on that null position further on in the test).

So now I'm wondering if I'm approaching this issue the wrong way and have to do further operations to actually remove the value from the position without sort of messing up the position itself so next time I use table_insert, the position will be empty and another key & value pair will be inserted in that spot.

```
int saveRemovedIndex = -1;

/* Check if the key already exists */
for(int indexCounter = 0; indexCounter <= MAXINDEX; indexCounter++){
    i = array_inspectValue(t->values, indexCounter);
    if (t->cf(i->key,key)==0) {
        saveRemovedIndex = indexCounter;
        break;
    }
}

/* Checks if the key actually exists in the table.
*  If it exists, remove it. Else quit.*/
if (saveRemovedIndex != -1) {
    i = array_inspectValue(t->values, saveRemovedIndex);
    if(t->keyFree!=NULL) {
        t->keyFree(i->key);
    }
    if(t->valueFree!=NULL) {
        t->valueFree(i->value);
    }
} else {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Whenever I see a `for` loop with a condition like `indexCounter <= MAXINDEX` is become suspicious, especially with variables or symbolic constants with "index" in their name. Since array-indexes are zero based, the top valid index is not e.g. `SIZE` but `SIZE - 1`. Are you *sure* about the loop condition? Also, will all elements of your "array" be initialized or could some elements be uninitialized? Or (in your case I guess) be null pointers?

Comment: Yes, upon defining the size of the array I made it 10001 therefore I have to use <= to make sure it checks the last one as well. Therefore I don't believe it's an off by 1 issue. Upon creating the table, calloc is used. So I guess all are set to 0 and not nuil. If that's what you meant.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: it would be helpful if you provided the code for the `array_setVal` function. It's hard to make assumptions about something we can't see. Please read this: [mcve].

Comment: On most systems, zero is equal to null. So by allocating an array of pointers and setting all elements to zero then you are creating an array of null pointers. Which you probably should check for. Or have some way to get the current *size* of the array (as opposed to its *capacity*). Preferably you need to handle both (size check and null pointer check).

Comment: Just noticed that the array_setVal has no code regarding any invalid index. By removing the key & value pair all I want is to return to the state the index had when the table was originally created.